# Bash: Loop through each file in each subfolder and rename

Tags: bash

I'm in a directory with 3 subdirectories: `sub1`, `sub2`, and `sub3`.  Each subdirectory has files in it.  I would like to rename each file by prepending `sample_` to it.

Here's what I have:

```
for d in */; do
    for f in "$d"; do
        mv "$f" "sample_$f"
    done
done
```

This prepends to the folder name, which isn't what I want.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to do a lot of this kind of stuff, and can install other software (or are using a Debian-based system), I strongly recommend [rename(1p)](http://code.tools/man/1p/file-rename/), or other `rename` / `prename` utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this with `find` and brace expansion (part of shell expansion):

```
find . -type f -execdir mv {,sample_}{} \;
```

This should recursively find *only* files (`-type f`) within each subdirectory then move them (renaming them) using the `-execdir` option  (see below), prepending `sample_` to each filename. The remaining `mv {,_sample}{}` is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)  way of doing `mv {} sample_{}`.

> <sub>**`-execdir command {} +`** Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory
>   containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in
>   which you started find. This a much more secure method for invoking
>   commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths
>   to the matched files. As with the `-exec` option, the '`+`' form of
>   `-execdir` will build a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given invocation of command will only list files that
>   exist in the same subdirectory. If you use this option, you must
>   ensure that your `$PATH` environment variable does not reference the
>   current directory; otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they
>   like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which
>   you will run `-execdir`.</sub>

↳ [GNU : Brace / Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `dirname` and `basename` to split your file name.

```
for d in */; do
    for f in $d/*; do
        mv  "$f" "$d/sample_$(basename $f)"
    done
done
```